# Entity Framework multiple where conditions, looking for correctness or better way

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I am attempting to load customer objects from my database where the customer's name can contain a specific string as well as any associated addresses having particular values in particular fields.  I have done a good bit of research, etc. to put this together.  Is this the proper way to construct such a query and if not, what is the "more correct" approach or more efficient approach?  Thanks for your time.

I own LINQPad and this query was crafted using it.

```
var customerName = "J";
var street = "Rd";
var city = "asdf";
var state = "TN";
var zip = "27613";

var query = (
    from c in customers
        .Include("locations")
        .Include("locations.address")
    where
        c.name.Contains(customerName) ||
        c.locations.Any(l => l.address.street1.Contains(street)) ||
        c.locations.Any(l => l.address.street2.Contains(street)) ||
        c.locations.Any(l => l.address.city.Contains(city)) ||
        c.locations.Any(l => l.address.state.Contains(state)) ||
        c.locations.Any(l => l.address.zip.Contains(zip))
    select new
    {
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.locationId,
        c.location,
        Locations = 
            from l in c.locations 
            where 
                l.address.street1.Contains(street) || 
                l.address.street2.Contains(street) || 
                l.address.city.Contains(city) ||
                l.address.state.Contains(state) ||
                l.address.zip.Contains(zip)
            select new
            {
                l.id,
                l.address,
                l.description,
                l.locationType
            }
    }
);

query.Dump();
```

This does give me the desired results, but I want to make sure I am doing this the best way that is the most polite to the database.

I'm sure this is a pretty typical pattern of searching using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write this big predicate twice, I'd flip it around. Also, the `Include`s are totally unnecessary when you're projecting.

```
var query = 
    from l in c.locations
    where 
        l.customer.name.Contains(customerName) ||
        l.address.street1.Contains(street) || 
        l.address.street2.Contains(street) || 
        l.address.city.Contains(city) ||
        l.address.state.Contains(state) ||
        l.address.zip.Contains(zip)
    group l by l.customer into g
    select new
    {
        id = g.Key.id,
        name = g.Key.name,
        // etc.
        Locations = from l2 in g
                    select new
                    {
                        l2.id,
                        l2.address,
                        l2.description,
                        l2.locationType
                    }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. Your answer has shown me some more possibilities using grouping.  My search spec has been changed to an AND condition instead of OR'ing everything, so I am going to use your example and tweak it to avoid the double predicates if possible.